# Need a way to only return data with a specific column entry

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a homework problem where it states the following: "List all products where the product cost is greater than all individual product costs of products whose vendors are based in Florida"

I made a block of code that follows a logic to return the needed data but it is not returning data correctly

Drafted a block of code that uses the logic to filter the data I am looking for, unfortunately it does not work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P_DESCRIPT FROM product
-- select relevant column from table
join vendor
on vendor.V_CODE = product.V_CODE
-- join table and bridge data
where
P_PRICE > (P_PRICE AND vendor.V_STATE = 'FL')
/* Filter data to display only products that have a greater price than
products from florida vendors. */
;
```

When I run this it returns all the products from the product table including ones that are not from florida vendors

Comment: Hint: The [`ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/all-subqueries.html) operator could be used in one possible approach taking the exercise text very literally.

Comment: @stickybit . I went ahead and read the link and  I put an all operator on this line of code


P_PRICE >  all (P_PRICE AND vendor.V_STATE = 'FL')



SQL is returning that Select is not in a valid position for this server version

Comment: @stickybit I also tried this: P_PRICE >  (all (select P_PRICE AND vendor.V_STATE = 'FL' from vendor))

Same error as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from product t
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from product p inner join vendor v
  on v.v_code = p.v_code
  where 
    p.p_price > t.p_price
    and
    v.v_state = 'FL' 
)
```

or:

```
select * from product
where p_price > (
  select max(p.p_price)
  from product p inner join vendor v
  on v.v_code = p.v_code
  where 
    v.v_state = 'FL' 
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me understand why it is that when I write it Like this:
SELECT * from product
where not exists (select 1 from product inner join vendor on vendor.V_CODE = product.V_CODE
where product.P_PRICE > product.P_PRICE AND vendor.V_STATE = 'FL');

It still returns all products without filtering?

Comment: `product.P_PRICE > product.P_PRICE` is always FALSE so NOT EXISTS returns always TRUE.